# Yii2 Conditional Url routing

Tags: routes, yii2, url-routing

I want to change the Url.
This is what I have used but its not working in second case.It gives me 404

```
Case 1:  user/view?id=35
[
    'pattern' => 'view-user-<id>',
    'route' => 'user/view',
    'suffix' => '.php',
],
Case 1 result: view-user-35.php

Case 2: user/view?id=35&tab=4
[
    'pattern' =>'view-user-<id>-<tab>',
    'route' => 'view-user-<id>.php',
    'suffix' => '.php',
],
Case 2 result: view-user-35.php?tab=4

but after refreshing the page it says 404 page not found. 
Case 2 expected result : view-user-35-4.php.
```

Here tab="any number" is conditional. It can there or it can not be there.

Note: tab is appended by using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for this question this is what I tried for now and working for me.

```
 [
   'pattern' =>'view-user-<id>-<tab>',
   'route' => 'view-user-<id>.php',
   'suffix' => '.php',
   'defaults' => array('tab' => '')
 ],
```